# REST HTTP Response Code when 3rd party ressource became unaviable

Tags: rest, conventions

in one scenario i got some data from client. With this client i want to start a booking.
Now it could be possible that the booking can't be done. For example when the ressource is sold out und became unaviable.

What would be a good reponse code for this?

I tested some apis and found there is often 500, 400,404 as a result.
A 500 looks just weired for me.
Also 400 is strange, because the api didn't do any wrong.
404 doesn't feel right, because the ressource is there, it just can't be bought right now.

Any advice on best practice?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible http error codes to use for this is 410: Gone.

The explanation for this code:

> Indicates that the resource requested is no longer available and will
>   not be available again. This should be used when a resource has been
>   intentionally removed and the resource should be purged. Upon
>   receiving a 410 status code, the client should not request the
>   resource again in the future. Clients such as search engines should
>   remove the resource from their indices.  Most use cases do not require
>   clients and search engines to purge the resource, and a "404 Not
>   Found" may be used instead.